Laravel dom-pdf not generate more then 2 page
In my project, I want to create a PDF, but when I create a PDF using the Laravel DOM PDF package, only a 2-page PDF is generated. After the second page, the content is cut off. So how to fix this problem ?
$pdfName = 'door_report.pdf';
$viewName = 'pdf.door_report';

$data = Door::whereId(11)->first();

$pdf = Pdf::setOptions(['isHTML5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true, '']);
$pdf->loadView($viewName, ['data' => $data]);
return $pdf->stream();

enter image description here
All Page pdf will generate and not cut any content.
